# Why is my CMFCToolBar overlapped on CDialog?

Tags: c++, dialog, cmfctoolbar

I am at the design stage here.

Code:

```
if (m_ToolBar.CreateEx(this, TBSTYLE_TRANSPARENT | TBSTYLE_FLAT,
    AFX_DEFAULT_TOOLBAR_STYLE, CRect(1, 1, 1, 1), IDR_TOOLBAR))
{
    m_ToolBar.SetPaneStyle(m_ToolBar.GetPaneStyle()
        & ~(CBRS_GRIPPER | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC | CBRS_BORDER_ANY));

    m_ToolBar.SetBorders();

    m_ToolBar.LoadBitmap(IDB_BMP_SM_IMAGELIST);

    m_ToolBar.InsertButton(CMFCToolBarButton(ID_FILE_OPEN_CHRISTIAN_LIFE_AND_MINISTRY_REPORT, 0, _T("Open MWB"), TRUE));
    m_ToolBar.InsertButton(CMFCToolBarButton(ID_FILE_CREATE_CHRISTIAN_LIFE_AND_MINISTRY_REPORT, 0, _T("Create MWB"), TRUE));
    m_ToolBar.InsertSeparator(2);
    m_ToolBar.InsertButton(CMFCToolBarButton(ID_FILE_OPENREPORT, 0, _T("Open SRR"), TRUE));
    m_ToolBar.InsertButton(CMFCToolBarButton(ID_FILE_CREATEREPORT, 0, _T("Create SRR"), TRUE));
    m_ToolBar.InsertSeparator(5);
    m_ToolBar.InsertButton(CMFCToolBarButton(ID_OPTIONS_PUBLISHERS_DATABASE, 0, _T("Publishers Database"), TRUE));


    CSize   sizeToolBar = m_ToolBar.CalcFixedLayout(FALSE, TRUE);
    m_ToolBar.SetWindowPos(NULL, 0, 10, sizeToolBar.cx, sizeToolBar.cy,
        SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOZORDER);

}
```

I call the above in `OnInitDialog` of my `CDialog`.

Why is the toolbar overlapped:

[image]

## Update

I simplified the code to just use a basic toolbar resource:

```
if (m_ToolBar.CreateEx(this, TBSTYLE_TRANSPARENT | TBSTYLE_FLAT,
    AFX_DEFAULT_TOOLBAR_STYLE, CRect(1, 1, 1, 1), IDR_TOOLBAR))
{
    m_ToolBar.SetPaneStyle(m_ToolBar.GetPaneStyle()
        & ~(CBRS_GRIPPER | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC | CBRS_BORDER_ANY));

    m_ToolBar.SetBorders();

    m_ToolBar.LoadToolBar(IDR_TOOLBAR);

    CSize   sizeToolBar = m_ToolBar.CalcFixedLayout(TRUE, TRUE);
    m_ToolBar.SetWindowPos(NULL, 0, 10, sizeToolBar.cx, sizeToolBar.cy,
        SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOZORDER);
}
```

But the results are still the same.

## Update

I noticed if I just resize my dialog in the IDE that I then have room for the toolbar. But how to do I accurately resize it in the IDE to allow for a 32 pixel high toolbar?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone provided a link to this archived [article](https://jeffpar.github.io/kbarchive/kb/141/Q141751/).

This is my updated code (called from `OnInitDialog`):

```
void CMeetingScheduleAssistantDlg::CreateToolbar()
{
    DWORD dwCtrlStyle = TBSTYLE_FLAT | TBSTYLE_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC;
    DWORD dwStyle = AFX_DEFAULT_TOOLBAR_STYLE;
    if (m_ToolBar.CreateEx(this, dwCtrlStyle,
        dwStyle, CRect(1, 1, 1, 1), IDR_TOOLBAR))
    {
        dwStyle = CBRS_TOOLTIPS | CBRS_FLYBY | CBRS_SIZE_DYNAMIC;
        m_ToolBar.SetPaneStyle(m_ToolBar.GetPaneStyle() | dwStyle);

        CMFCToolBarInfo info;

        info.m_uiColdResID = IDB_PNG_MAIN_TOOLBAR;
        info.m_uiHotResID = IDB_PNG_MAIN_TOOLBAR;
        info.m_uiLargeColdResID = IDB_PNG_MAIN_TOOLBAR;
        info.m_uiLargeHotResID = IDB_PNG_MAIN_TOOLBAR;

        m_ToolBar.LoadToolBarEx(IDR_TOOLBAR, info, FALSE);

        CSize   sizeToolBar = m_ToolBar.CalcFixedLayout(TRUE, TRUE);
        m_ToolBar.SetWindowPos(NULL, 0, 0, sizeToolBar.cx, sizeToolBar.cy,
            SWP_NOACTIVATE | SWP_NOZORDER);

        // Move all controls down
        CPoint ptOffset(0, sizeToolBar.cy);

        CRect  rcChild;
        CWnd* pwndChild = GetWindow(GW_CHILD);
        while (pwndChild)
        {
            if (pwndChild->GetSafeHwnd() != m_ToolBar.GetSafeHwnd())
            {
                pwndChild->GetWindowRect(rcChild);
                ScreenToClient(rcChild);
                rcChild.OffsetRect(ptOffset);
                pwndChild->MoveWindow(rcChild, FALSE);
            }
            pwndChild = pwndChild->GetNextWindow();
        }

        // Resize the window
        CRect rcWindow;
        GetWindowRect(rcWindow);
        rcWindow.bottom += sizeToolBar.cy;
        MoveWindow(rcWindow, FALSE);

    }
}
```

In short I had to manually move down all controls and resize the window. Looks OK now:

[image: New Toolbar]